# NullPointerException at if (runPrevious.equals("yes")) {

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to setup a method of executing one task if my application has been run previously - and another task if it has not.

To do this I have created a `String runPrevious`:

My problem is every time I attempt to execute the application I get a force close due to a null pointer exception here:

```
if (runPrevious.equals("yes")) {
```

which I don't understand - since I'm declaring the value of the String here:

```
String runPrevious = "No";
```

### LOGCAT:

```
12-13 13:20:12.485: E/AndroidRuntime(1803): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 13:20:12.485: E/AndroidRuntime(1803): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.idg.omv/com.idg.omv.ui.phone.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 13:20:12.485: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
12-13 13:20:12.485: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
12-13 13:20:12.485: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
12-13 13:20:12.485: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
12-13 13:20:12.485: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-13 13:20:12.485: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
12-13 13:20:12.485: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
12-13 13:20:12.485: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 13:20:12.485: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-13 13:20:12.485: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
12-13 13:20:12.485: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-13 13:20:12.485: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-13 13:20:12.485: E/AndroidRuntime(1803): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 13:20:12.485: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at com.idg.omv.ui.phone.Home.onCreate(Home.java:113)
12-13 13:20:12.485: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5262)
12-13 13:20:12.485: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
12-13 13:20:12.485: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
12-13 13:20:12.485: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     ... 11 more
12-13 13:20:13.969: I/Process(1803): Sending signal. PID: 1803 SIG: 9
```

### JAVA

```
public class Home extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements

VideoClickListener {
    String runPrevious = "No";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);



        String runPrevious = getIntent().getStringExtra("runPrevious");

        if (runPrevious.equals("yes")) {


            String playlist = getIntent().getStringExtra("playlist");   
            new GetYouTubeUserVideosTask(responseHandler, playlist).execute();
        }else{


            new GetYouTubeUserVideosTask(responseHandler, playlist).execute();  


        }
```

Comment: Well... you're shadowing runPrevious in the precedent line...

Comment: `getStringExtra()` can return null. Show us how you put this value in the previous activity.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring it once again (probably with null value)

```
String runPrevious = getIntent().getStringExtra("runPrevious");
```

Answer (score 1):

do not test strings for null if you are comparing them to a literal value.  Instead use non-null-pointer succeptible compairsons.

In your case:

```
if ("yes".equals(runPrevious))
```

This will *never* throw a null pointer exception.

Comment: While a good practice, still not the issue. So, +1 for doing it the right way around, -1 for not answering the question ;) In this case, the NPE actually makes the problem easier to find, rather than the condition always being false.